# How to prove that $[0, 1) \text{ and } (0, 2]$ have the same cardinality using Bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am just starting out with bijection, so my knowledge of it is very sparse.
I am trying to prove that $[0, 1) \text{ and } (0, 2]$ have the same cardinality using a bijection. But I have no idea of even where to begin.

I have googled it, but all the examples seem to be for all open or all closed intervals, none for half and half like this.

If someone wouldnt mind explaining how I can prove this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: First find a bijection $f:[0,1)\to(0,1]$. Then find a bijection $g:(0,1]\to(0,2]$. Find $f\circ g$.

Answer (score 6):

Send $x\in [0,1)$ to $2-2x$.

Call this function $f$. We need to check three things:

- That $f$ doesn't take you outside $(0, 2]$
- That $f$ is injective
- That $f$ is surjective

First point: If we have $x \in [0, 1)$, another way of saying this is that $0\leq x < 1$. We have:
$$
0 \leq x < 1\\
0 \leq 2x < 2\\
0 \geq -2x > -2\\
2 \geq 2-2x > 0\\
2 \geq f(x) > 0
$$which means exactly that $f(x) \in (0, 2]$, so the first point is proven.

Second point: If we have $x, y \in [0, 1)$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$, then this implies
$$
f(x) = f(y)\\
2-2x = 2-2y\\
-\!2x = -2y\\
x = y
$$
which means that the function is injective.

Third point: If we have a $c \in (0, 2]$, we want an $x\in [0, 1)$ such that $f(x) = c$. This $x$ is given by 
$$
f(x) = c\\
2-2x = c\\
-2x = c-2\\
x = \frac{c-2}{-2} \\
x = \frac{2-c}{2}
$$
so if we have a $c$, then $f\left(\frac{2-c}{2}\right) = c$. It remains to show that this is in the valid domain $[0, 1)$ of $f$, but that proof is more or less equal to the proof of the first point.

Comment: Hey, Thanks heaps for your response, it is much appreciated. However I am still a bit lost as to how I would go about constructing a proof using this . I dont suppose you would be able to expand on it a bit? If not no worries. Thanks again, Corey :)

Comment: @Fishingfon: Let $f(x)=2-2x$. Show that if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$; this proves that $f$ is an injection. Then show that if $y\in(0,2]$, there is an $x\in[0,1)$ such that $f(x)=y$; this proves that $f$ is a surjection.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You forgot the first point: That $f$ is indeed a function into $(0, 2]$. I'll add some details to my answer.

Comment: @Arthur: No, I didn’t forget; I took it for granted that the OP would realize that much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: (0, 2] \to [0, 2)$ be defined as $$f(x) := \begin{cases} x \, , & x \neq 2 \\ 0 \, , & x = 2 \end{cases} \; .$$ Then $f$ is a bijection between $(0,2]$ and $[0,2)$.  So it's enough to find find a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $[0,2)$. So define $g: [0,1) \to [0,2)$ as $g(x) := 2x$. Now 
$f^{-1} \circ g$ is a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $(0,2]$, so $[0,1)$ and $(0,2]$ have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

You have given the bijective function $f:[0,1)\rightarrow(0,2]$ defined by

$f(x)=2\cdot(1-x)$

You can verify the bijectivity by examining the function for surjectivity and injectivity:

- For a injective function $f:A\rightarrow B$: $f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$
- For a surjective function $f:A\rightarrow B$: $\forall b\exists a:f(a)=b$

(both cases $a\in A$ and $b\in B$)

So let's look at our function $f(x)=2\cdot(1-x)$:

**Injectivity**

$f(a)=f(b)$

$2-2a=2-2b$

$a=b$

So $f(x)$ is injective.

**Surjectivity**

Given any $b\in(0,2]$, you can find an $a\in[0,1)$ by the inverse function of $f(x)$:

$a = \dfrac{b+2}{2}$

I won't go into detail any more because in this example the bijectivity is immediately apparent (because $f(x)$ is linear), but I think you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

At first is well if we think in this question, how to proof tha $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ have the same cardinality, this is a easy question, because if you put 
the line passing through the point $(0,0)$ ; $(1,2)$ (note that is a general way to proof that (a,b) have the same cardinality to (c,d) using the line with points     (a,c) and (b,d)) so you get a bijecction $f$ and at the end you define $f(0)=2$ to get all the intervals. ;)